What is the Hamas stance on the recognition of Palestinian state by Spain and Ireland?
Spain and Ireland (and possibly other countries) prepare to recognize the Palestinian state - this recognition however amounts to recognition of the Palestinian Authority, which western governments treat as the sole legitimate representative of the Palestinian people. However, the Palestinian Authority is engaged in a bitter conflict with Hamas, the latter rejecting the international agreements made by PA in the name of the Palestinian people. Moreover, despite the PA anti-Israel rhetoric, it is potentially the main beneficiary from the war in Gaza, if Israel succeeds in removing Hamas and the US convinces Israel that Gaza should return to PA rule. Indeed, this is the current US position, and Spain and Ireland will be essentially recognizing PA as the only legitimate government in Gaza.

Has Hamas made statements about the impending recognition?
Have any pro-Palestinian groups opposed recognition of Palestine, as detrimental to the Palestinian struggle headed by Hamas?


Just a note for answers: Any answers should consider not just the statements Hamas makes in English, but especially the ones they make in Arabic. These are often not identical, and sometimes outright contradict each other.

Why don't you talk about Norway?

@BCLC Spain and Ireland (and possibly other countries) - at the moment of writing it was expected that at least 5 countries would recognize Palestine, but Spain and Ireland were leading the charge.

Per the BBC, Hamas have just responded:

In a statement to AFP, Bassem Naim, a senior Hamas figure, says the "brave resistance" of the Palestinian people is behind the move.
"These successive recognitions are the direct result of this brave resistance and the legendary steadfastness of the Palestinian people," he says.
"We believe this will be a turning point in the international position on the Palestinian issue."

So it seems that Hamas approve of the recognition, despite the fact that they themselves are not the ones being recognised.

I wonder if they'll address the issue that the Palestine being recognized is not "from the river to the sea", but rather recognizes Israeli lands as well?  But no surprise they talk it up as an achievement of theirs.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: given the statements from the 3 countries, it's not unreasonable to assume that without Oct7 and its aftermath, they might not have come out that strongly or right now. But most of the 'credit' goes to Netanyahu for the way he conducted the war/reprisals and lack of any vision beyond more occupation for the 'day after', it seems.

@againstverylongusernames lack of any vision beyond more occupation for the 'day after', it seems - why say such nonsense? - not only has he a vision, but it differs from the one promoted by the US One may disagree with it in moral terms, but which vision is more realistic is far from a foregone conclusion.


Hamas won the elections in 2006, --- PA, Israel and US didnt like it, but regardless, Hamas is confident that if there is a Palestinian state, it will be the one governing. 2) Hamas put it down in their 2017 program that Palestinian state is envisioned in West Bank and Gaza, which is to say they were prepared to negotiate with Israel and recognize 1967 lines. Unfortunately for them and Israel, it happened to be a time when Trump was president...


@Kphysics your comment is highly misleading - 2006 was 18 years ago. Hamas lost its legal legitimacy, since there were no elections after that, and, moreover, it engaged in an armed rebellion against the Palestinian Authority (internationally recognized Palestinian government). Furthermore, Hamas popularity has recently decreased due to the hardships that its brinkmanship brought to Palestinians. Also, Hamas accepts 1967 border as an intermediate solution, but it has never renounced its intention of 'liberating all Palestine' - see their 2017 covenant.

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad: "internal governance would be Palestinian" (from your linked answer). That's alas window dressing to anyone but himself and you. Even his IDF chief of staff says Bibi has no actual plan how to make that happen--because Bibi rejects any Palestinian actor of consequence. So, empty talk, essentially. Maybe those tribal leaders will rise against Hamas and form a government after the Rafah offensive, but it seems few believe that will actually happen--IDF included.

And yeah, after Halevi, Gallant said the same thing.

"So it seems that Hamas approve of the recognition, despite the fact that they themselves are not the ones being recognised" => recognition of states is distinct from recognition of governments. The first means you agree the state exists, the second means you agree with group X's claim to be its legitimate government. 2nd requires 1st but logically distinct. Hamas claims that they, not the Ramallah administration, are the legitimate government of the State of Palestine. So of course they'd welcome that Spain/Ireland/etc now agree with them on issue 1, despite still disagreeing on issue 2

"@Kphysics your comment is highly misleading - 2006 was 18 years ago. Hamas lost its legal legitimacy, since there were no elections after that, and, moreover, it engaged in an armed rebellion against the Palestinian Authority " -- Not like there were many elections in West Bank by PA since then.

@Colombo this is also true - Spain and Ireland have just recognized a de facto dictatorship.

@againstverylongusernames That's alas window dressing to anyone but himself and you. - what's your problem really? If you are believing that western politics is guided by moral principles, I have a bridge in Brooklyn that I could sell you.

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad, I tried to make a factual statement, not moral or a forecast. Hamas does indeed believe it will be governing all of Gaza and West Bank. Also it is a fact that they are popular in West Bank, but maybe less popular than before in Gaza. If you live in Israel, this is supposed to make you wander if Israeli policy to keep the PA weak and corrupt is smart thing to do or not.

First of all, it's worth emphasising that whilst none of the G7 group of countries recognise the Palestinian state, around 140 of the 193 states belonging to the UN already do. The recent recognition by Ireland, Spain and Norway further isolates the G7 position.
It's also worth reminding ourselves that Hamas released a charter in 2017 that accepted a Palestinian state in the 1967 borders without recognising Israel. Further CNN have reported that some members of Hamas' political bureau have signalled that Hamas would give up the armed struggle if such a Palestinian state - with its capital in Jerusalem and the right of return recognised - was established with Hamas fighters folded into the states army.
Given this, it is no surprise that the Daily Mail reported that Hamas welcomed the move and urged other countries to follow suit saying, "We consider this an important step towards affirming our right to our land," it said, calling "on countries around the world to recognise our legitimate national rights".
